# My INNER SELECT does not prompt the right output

Tags: sql, select, inner-join

It's been 2 weeks since I'm doing this report. I need to finish this today but still I could not find any solutions with this query. I know where my error is going (it is on my **INNER SELECT not having a GROUP BY ItemCode**) but **I cannot group it by ItemCode on the INNER SELECT because I have a GROUP BY on my OUTER SELECT**.

I would have an error in my code if I put the GROUP BY inside the inner query and the error is:
"**Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.**"

This is my code, it is running but the Depreciation sums up all the values in the whole year per month:

```
DROP PROCEDURE dfsi_sp_FALS2
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dfsi_sp_FALS2
@filterDate DATE
AS


SELECT ODPV.ItemCode, OITM.ItemName, ITM8.APC, ITM7.UsefulLife, SUM(ODPV.OrdDprPost) AS AccumulatedDep,
(ITM8.APC - SUM(ODPV.OrdDprPost)) AS NBV, 
(SELECT SUM(ODPV.OrdDprPost) FROM ODPV WHERE ODPV.FromDate = '2014-01-01 00:00:00' AND 
ODPV.ToDate = '2014-01-31 00:00:00' GROUP BY ODPV.ItemCode) AS DateofJanuary,
(SELECT SUM(ODPV.OrdDprPost) FROM ODPV WHERE ODPV.FromDate = '2014-02-01 00:00:00' AND 
ODPV.ToDate = '2014-02-28 00:00:00') AS DateofFebruary,
(SELECT SUM(ODPV.OrdDprPost) FROM ODPV WHERE ODPV.FromDate = '2014-03-01 00:00:00' AND 
ODPV.ToDate = '2014-03-31 00:00:00') AS DateofMarch,
(SELECT SUM(ODPV.OrdDprPost) FROM ODPV WHERE ODPV.FromDate = '2014-04-01 00:00:00' AND 
ODPV.ToDate = '2014-04-30 00:00:00') AS DateofApril,
(SELECT SUM(ODPV.OrdDprPost) FROM ODPV WHERE ODPV.FromDate = '2014-05-01 00:00:00' AND 
ODPV.ToDate = '2014-05-31 00:00:00') AS DateofMay,
(SELECT SUM(ODPV.OrdDprPost) FROM ODPV WHERE ODPV.FromDate = '2014-06-01 00:00:00' AND 
ODPV.ToDate = '2014-06-30 00:00:00') AS DateofJune,
(SELECT SUM(ODPV.OrdDprPost) FROM ODPV WHERE ODPV.FromDate = '2014-07-01 00:00:00' AND 
ODPV.ToDate = '2014-07-31 00:00:00') AS DateofJuly,
(SELECT SUM(ODPV.OrdDprPost) FROM ODPV WHERE ODPV.FromDate = '2014-08-01 00:00:00' AND 
ODPV.ToDate = '2014-08-31 00:00:00') AS DateofAugust,
(SELECT SUM(ODPV.OrdDprPost) FROM ODPV WHERE ODPV.FromDate = '2014-09-01 00:00:00' AND 
ODPV.ToDate = '2014-09-30 00:00:00') AS DateofSeptember,
(SELECT SUM(ODPV.OrdDprPost) FROM ODPV WHERE ODPV.FromDate = '2014-10-01 00:00:00' AND 
ODPV.ToDate = '2014-10-31 00:00:00') AS DateofOctober,
(SELECT SUM(ODPV.OrdDprPost) FROM ODPV WHERE ODPV.FromDate = '2014-11-01 00:00:00' AND 
ODPV.ToDate = '2014-11-30 00:00:00') AS DateofNovember,
(SELECT SUM(ODPV.OrdDprPost) FROM ODPV WHERE ODPV.FromDate = '2014-12-01 00:00:00' AND 
ODPV.ToDate = '2014-12-31 00:00:00') AS DateofDecember


FROM ODPV 
INNER JOIN OITM ON OITM.ItemCode = ODPV.ItemCode    
INNER JOIN ITM7 ON ITM7.ItemCode = ODPV.ItemCode
INNER JOIN ITM8 ON ITM8.ItemCode = ODPV.ItemCode

WHERE
ODPV.DprArea = 'Main Area' AND ODPV.PeriodCat = @filterDate
GROUP BY  ODPV.ItemCode, OITM.ItemName, ITM8.APC, ITM7.UsefulLife

GO

EXEC dfsi_sp_FALS2 '2014';
```

The depreciation per month columns would result to this if I run that query above:

```
Date of September:
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
432803.387566
```

This code is what I need but I can't do it on my query because this code should be in the inner select:

```
SELECT SUM(ODPV.OrdDprPost) AS DateofSeptember FROM ODPV WHERE ODPV.FromDate = '2014-10-01 00:00:00'
AND ODPV.ToDate = '2014-10-31 00:00:00'  GROUP BY ODPV.ItemCode;
```

That code above would result to this (the result that I want (this is a Depreciation on September on each ItemCode)):

```
10200.000000
0.000000
0.000000
2921.000000
498.000000
1030.000000
0.000000
0.000000
427.000000
327.000000
0.000000
291.000000
30.000000
13.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
1899.000000
0.000000
1439.000000
28.000000
190.000000
18.000000
516.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
121.000000
121.000000
354.000000
382.000000
32.000000
588.000000
127.000000
88.000000
88.000000
0.000000
0.000000
388.000000
340.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
79.000000
457.000000
457.000000
167.000000
181.000000
213.000000
107.000000
82.000000
81.000000
135.000000
0.000000
217.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
35.000000
35.000000
35.000000
43.000000
18.000000
18.000000
2.000000
50.000000
174.000000
53.000000
29.000000
26.000000
48.000000
333.000000
27.000000
662.000000
1660.000000
1109.000000
154.000000
112.000000
218.000000
423.000000
85.000000
265.000000
221.000000
134.000000
1349.000000
21.000000
34.000000
54.000000
0.000000
121.000000
128.000000
83.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
616.000000
614.000000
1666.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
469.000000
1120.000000
9.000000
20.000000
99.000000
99.000000
152.000000
18.000000
656.000000
108.000000
84.000000
84.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
1188.000000
59.000000
0.000000
90.000000
90.000000
86.000000
86.000000
29.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
934.000000
934.000000
164.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
104.000000
338.000000
338.000000
338.000000
284.000000
254.000000
35.000000
45.000000
45.000000
45.000000
168.000000
162.000000
162.000000
273.000000
275.000000
32.000000
609.000000
72.000000
72.000000
0.000000
0.000000
51.000000
```

I know why it sums up but I can't GROUP BY my INNER QUERY because it would have an error.

I need your help guys pleaseeee. Thank you very much. I would appreciate all your suggestions.

Comment: may be your inner query return more than 1 values

Comment: The error: "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression." prompts when I would put a group by on my inner query. I need to group by my inner query so that I would get the right result or there's an alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what exactly the question. It would be easy if you have simplified requirement, like very simple example...

As per my understanding you are trying to get sum per each month for each item code. If it is then try the query given below.

```
SELECT Od.ItemCode, OITM.ItemName, ITM8.APC, ITM7.UsefulLife, SUM(Od.OrdDprPost) AS AccumulatedDep,
(ITM8.APC - SUM(Od.OrdDprPost)) AS NBV, 
(SELECT SUM(OdJ.OrdDprPost) FROM ODPV OdJ WHERE OdJ.FromDate = '2014-01-01 00:00:00' AND OdJ.ToDate = '2014-01-31 00:00:00' AND OdJ.ItemCode = Od.ItemCode) AS DateofJanuary,
(SELECT SUM(OdF.OrdDprPost) FROM ODPV OdF WHERE OdF.FromDate = '2014-02-01 00:00:00' AND OdF.ToDate = '2014-02-28 00:00:00' AND OdF.ItemCode = Od.ItemCode) AS DateofFebruary    

FROM ODPV Od
INNER JOIN OITM ON OITM.ItemCode = Od.ItemCode    
INNER JOIN ITM7 ON ITM7.ItemCode = Od.ItemCode
INNER JOIN ITM8 ON ITM8.ItemCode = Od.ItemCode

WHERE
Od.DprArea = 'Main Area' AND Od.PeriodCat = @filterDate
GROUP BY  Od.ItemCode, OITM.ItemName, ITM8.APC, ITM7.UsefulLife
```

I had given only Jan and FEB. Just copy the inner queries for each month and change the dates and Alias name within the subquery.

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your utmost help my friend. 

(SELECT SUM(OdJ.OrdDprPost) FROM ODPV OdJ WHERE OdJ.FromDate = '2014-01-01 00:00:00' AND OdJ.ToDate = '2014-01-31 00:00:00' Where OdJ.ItemCode = Od.ItemCode) AS DateofJanuary,

There are two (2) WHERE clause. I got an error. Is your syntax correct? I hope your query would run. Because I need to finish this now. Again thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: I found out that it was AND. Hey my friend, Thank you very much! You saved my day! :)
Have a good day too.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion..
Try creating a temp table within the Proc and dump all the inner select query outputs in it and join the temp table to other tables for overall output.

Comment: Hey my friend. Thank you for your suggestion.
I'm thinking of that awhile ago. But I don't know how to start doing it. But I'm open for learning so I would do that next time. This report needs to be urgent so I would prefer the first solution.
Thank you very much bro! That would also help me at some time. :)